Drawer navigation items
I am implementing drawer navigation for an app in expo but I find that when implementing  it lists all the screens and components inside the drawer, even when placing only one screen. Attached is the code.

// Expo
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Drawer } from 'expo-router/drawer';

// React-native
import { Button, View, Image } from 'react-native';

// Views
import MainHome from './homeScreen';

// Images && Icons
const selfie = require('../assets/man.avif');

const RootLayout = () => {
  return(
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Drawer>
        <Drawer.Screen 
        name="homeScreen"
        options={{title: 'Reportes Cercanos'}}
        />
      </Drawer>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>

  )
}

export default RootLayout;

The project structure is basic and is as follows.


Solved:
What was done was to put _layout.tsx inside the (private) group, which are the views I want to be seen in the drawer.
(private)
 _layout.tsx
 homeScreen.tsx
 ...

